# Making config settings configurable for user

Tags: sxa, sitecore-api, configuration

I am using Sitecore 9.3, SXA. I want to make some of the current config settings configurable from within Sitecore. I have created a template with all of the fields (e.g. MediaResponse single text field) and added it to the main site settings. I want to replace the current corresponding settings' values with the values in these fields.

e.g. I want replace the below value with the MediaResponse field value

```
<setting name="MediaResponse.MaxAge" value="5.00:00:00"/>
```

Comment: Please add further details to clarify your question. At the moment it is unclear what you are trying to do. What are the user defined settings? Who is the user, the content author or a site user? Which settings are you trying to override?

Comment: what kind of settings are you referring?

Comment: @jammykam I have updated the question

Comment: @VladIobagiu some config settings, I added an example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it not possible to update Sitecore settings value by the editors. Is not recommended to update these Sitecore values on runtime because it will restart your IIS/site.